# how to write internal jquery code in master page using asp.net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, master-pages, html

this could be an easy question but i couldn't do it.
i am using the following code in the header of the master page but it didn't working also when i place it in the other web page that are inherited from this master page.

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

         $("#txtdate1").datepicker();
         $("#txtdate2").datepicker();

     });


</script>`
```

this was working fine in the single web page but i don't know to use it in asp.net while using master page in asp.net.

help will highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that.. control's clientID getting changed.
You can try :
First approach :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#'<%=txtdate1.ClientID %>'").datepicker();    
   $("#'<%=txtdate2.ClientID %>'").datepicker();

  });
 </script>
```

Second approach :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $("[id$='txtdate1']").datepicker();    
     $("[id$='txtdate2']").datepicker();        
    });
   </script>
```

Third approach :

Make `ClientID="Static"` for the control, ID will be the same:

```
<asp:Textbox ID="txtdate1" runat="server" ClientID="Static" />
```

your same code will work :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

         $("#txtdate1").datepicker();
         $("#txtdate2").datepicker();    
     });
</script>
```

Comment: i couldn't give you the points because of  m new and have low reputation.:(

Comment: @user2384794 You can still accept his answer by ticking it. This link will show you what we mean - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/216011. Also you have 21 reputation, which is enough to upvote it as well :)

Answer (score 1):

can use `clientID` , `CSS selector` techniques for this purpose.

Eg.

```
$('#<%=txtdate1.ClientID%>').text();
```

**Refer:**

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/471799/jQuery-introduction-and-how-to-use-jQuery-with-ASP

Comment: thnx this is fine and helpful. but i couldn't give you the points because of  m new and have low reputation.

Comment: @user2384794 I think you have enough reputation to give us points.